# Correlated subquery in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables: Table A and Table B

1. Table A and Table B both have `RowId` column.
2. Table A and Table B both have `ModifiedAt` column.
3. Also Table A has a column called `Key`.

Check conditions :

1. Retrieve RowId's from table A if table A 'Key' = someconstant
2. Take those retrieved row Id's from `Table A` and check if `ModifiedAt` field of those rows is > ModifiedAT field of Table B with same rowId's.

Table `B` has no repetition of RowId's but Table `A` does.

What I tried on my own :

```
select *
from dbo.ResultsStored rs
WHERE HashedKey = hashbytes('MD5', @StringConcat) 
                       and 
                       rs.ModifiedAT > (select Max(ModifiedAt)
    from dbo.Patients P
    where P.RowId = rs.RowId)
```

Note :
Also , what surprises me is if I replace `rs.RowId` with hardcoded value say '1', it works but not this way.

Results when I hardcode rs.RowId :

```
if not exists (select * from dbo.ResultsStored RS where RS.HashedKey =  0xBBE4D4DC92C713756E6683ADD671F7DA and ModifiedAt > (select ModifiedAt from dbo.Patients where RowId = 1))
begin
print'not exists'
end
else
begin
print 'exists'
end
```

**OUTPUT** : not exists

```
if not exists (select * from dbo.ResultsStored RS where RS.HashedKey =  0xBBE4D4DC92C713756E6683ADD671F7DA and ModifiedAt > (select ModifiedAt from dbo.Patients where RowId = rs.RowId))
begin
print'not exists'
end
else
begin
print 'exists'
end
```

**`OUTPUT`** : exists

**Expected output** : not exists

Can I please get some help on this ?

Comment: Does B have more than 1 row for any A.RowId? When compared using > only one row may come from the sub-query.

Comment: No. B has unique RowId. I see it not working because if instead of A.RowId, I use a particular id say '1' it gives me expected results but not this way

Comment: What is the output of the above query? What is the issue?

Comment: @SelvaTS: Updated. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your data.
If I understand correctly you want to know if there are such rows in Results which date is greater then Patients date. If no such row is found then it is OK.

If so your query looks correct. You can directly select incorrect data by:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Patients p
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    MAX(ModifiedAt) AS ModifiedAt
                      FROM      ResultsStored rs
                      WHERE     p.RowId = rs.RowId
                    ) a
WHERE   a.ModifiedAt > p.ModifiedAt
```

Comment: My if logic itself was messed up. You made that clear. Thanks a ton

Answer (score -1):

DECLARE @RowId INT

DECLARE  CurRowId CURSOR FOR SELECT RowId FROM Patients

OPEN CurRowId

FETCH  NEXT FROM CurRowId INTO @RowId

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

if not exists (select * from dbo.ResultsStored where ModifiedAt >

```
                 (select ModifiedAt from dbo.Patients where RowId = 
                                                                   @RowId))
```

begin

print'not exists'

```
end

else

begin

print 'exists'

END

FETCH  NEXT FROM CurRowId INTO @RowId

END
```

Comment: I believe we can do this with Correlated subquery and do not need cursors here.

Comment: you want Patients wise exits not exits then Correlated subquery not work it gives only one output .