# writing a correlated subquery in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables: Table A and Table B

1. Table A and Table B both have `RowId` column.
2. Table A and Table B both have `ModifiedAt` column.
3. Also Table A has a column called `Key`.

Check conditions :

1. Retrieve RowId's from table A if table A 'Key' = someconstant
2. Take those retrieved row Id's from `Table A` and check if `ModifiedAt` field of those rows is > ModifiedAT field of Table B with same rowId's.

Table `B` has no repetition of RowId's but Table `A` does.

Note : I had asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938201/correlated-subquery-in-sql/28940454#28940454) and tried to write on my own as well but I failed.

What I tried on my own :

```
select *
from dbo.ResultsStored rs
WHERE HashedKey = hashbytes('MD5', @StringConcat) 
                       and 
                       rs.ModifiedAT > (select Max(ModifiedAt)
    from dbo.Patients P
    where P.RowId = rs.RowId)
```

Note :
Also , what surprises me is if I replace `rs.RowId` with hardcoded value say '1', it works but not this way.

Can I please get some help on this ?

Comment: School work? Show us your current query!

Comment: If you have already asked this question and are having problems implementing the answers then it is best to briefly discuss the answers via the comments facility. You may also move a discussion into chat.

Comment: @jarlh: Updated question with what my current query is and where I am stuck with its anomalous behavior.

Comment: If you want an answer to the question, edit your original question and provide sample data and desired results.  Your question is rather vague to someone who does not know your data.  Alternatively, you can delete that question, this question, and start over.  Did I mention to include sample data and desired results?

Comment: @GordonLinoff :Thanks .I  Updated the question on original post with outputs and specific confusion.